# Set minimum column width to header width in PyQt4 QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm working with the `QTableWidget` component in PyQt4 and I can't seem to get columns to size correctly, according to their respective header lengths.

Here's what the table layout should look like (sans pipes, obviously):

```
Index | Long_Header | Longer_Header
1     | 102402      | 100
2     | 123123      | 2
3     | 454689      | 18
```

The code I'm working with looks something like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import QStringList, QString
from PyQt4.QtGui  import QApplication, QMainWindow, QSizePolicy
from PyQt4.QtGui  import QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem

def createTable():
    table = QTableWidget(5, 3)
    table.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

    headers = QStringList()
    headers.append(QString("Index"))
    headers.append(QString("Long_Header"))
    headers.append(QString("Longer_Header"))

    table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers)
    table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

    # ignore crappy names -- this is just an example :)
    cell1 = QTableWidgetItem(QString("1"))
    cell2 = QTableWidgetItem(QString("102402"))
    cell3 = QTableWidgetItem(QString("100"))

    cell4 = QTableWidgetItem(QString("2"))
    cell5 = QTableWidgetItem(QString("123123"))
    cell6 = QTableWidgetItem(QString("2"))

    cell7 = QTableWidgetItem(QString("3"))
    cell8 = QTableWidgetItem(QString("454689"))
    cell9 = QTableWidgetItem(QString("18"))

    table.setItem(0, 0, cell1)
    table.setItem(0, 1, cell2)
    table.setItem(0, 2, cell3)
    table.setItem(1, 0, cell4)
    table.setItem(1, 1, cell5)
    table.setItem(1, 2, cell6)
    table.setItem(2, 0, cell7)
    table.setItem(2, 1, cell8)
    table.setItem(2, 2, cell9)

    return table

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainW = QMainWindow()

    mainW.setMinimumWidth(300)
    mainW.setCentralWidget(createTable())

    mainW.show()

    app.exec_()
```

When the application executes, the first column is quite wide while the other columns are somewhat compressed.

Is there a way to force the table to size according to the header widths, rather than the data itself?  Better yet, is there a way to force each column width to be the maximum width of the data and header values?

**Update**: I've tried calling `resizeColumnsToContents()` on the table, but the view becomes horribly mangled:

[Python Table http://img514.imageshack.us/img514/8633/tablef.png](http://img514.imageshack.us/img514/8633/tablef.png)

** Update2**: `resizeColumnsToContents()` works just fine as long as it's called **after** all cells and headers have been inserted into the table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
table.resizeColumnsToContents()
```

should do the trick for this specific example.

Be sure to bookmark the [PyQt documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/) if you haven't done so already (handy when you're looking for a specific function).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I already tried resizeColumnsToContents().  It resizes the columns to the data, and the headers become unreadable. I have the documentation present (I use it constantly), but I can't seem to find a solution to this vexing issue.

Comment: @bedwyr: Maybe the problem is triggered elsewhere (properties in a .ui (designer) file you inherit from perhaps?). I can't reproduce the problem here (PyQt 4.5.4 iirc, Mac). This is what your example code (with a simple `table.resizeColumnsToContents()` added) looks like: http://img210.imageshack.us/img210/9968/screenshot20100704at225.png

Comment: I've designed everything by hand (not using Qt Designer), so it's likely something I'm doing wrong :^)  I'm using 4.7.2 on Linux, so it's possible something is different in the Linux-port; I doubt it though. The problem is most likely on my end. I'll keep digging -- thanks!

Comment: I figured it out. The resizeColumnsToContents() works perfectly, but I need to call it _after_ I set the header labels :^) Thanks for the help!